# Can Altair do a window transform with interactive frame?

Tags: python, visualization, altair, vega-lite

I want to create a line chart in altair that has the raw data as background, and an *interactive* rolling average on top of that. This is possible in vega based on the [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/window/) for window transforms. However, I'm not sure how the syntax needs to be changed to accomplish it in vega-lite or altair, if they require a workaround I can't think of, or if it can be done with them at all.

Screenshot of the chart I'm trying to make below. I want the slider to change the rolling average window and therefore the red line. I get an error `{'params': 'op_var'} is not of type 'null', 'number'` when I try to pass any sort of variable to the `frame=[]` part of the code. Is there a way to do this in altair?

[image]

I'm using in a jupyter notebook in vs code, Altair version 5.0.0rc1

```
dfs=pd.DataFrame({'Date': {552: Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  553: Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  554: Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  555: Timestamp('2021-10-06 00:00:00'),
  556: Timestamp('2021-10-07 00:00:00'),
  557: Timestamp('2021-10-08 00:00:00'),
  558: Timestamp('2021-10-09 00:00:00'),
  559: Timestamp('2021-10-10 00:00:00'),
  560: Timestamp('2021-10-11 00:00:00'),
  561: Timestamp('2021-10-12 00:00:00'),
  562: Timestamp('2021-10-13 00:00:00'),
  563: Timestamp('2021-10-14 00:00:00'),
  564: Timestamp('2021-10-15 00:00:00'),
  565: Timestamp('2021-10-16 00:00:00'),
  566: Timestamp('2021-10-17 00:00:00'),
  567: Timestamp('2021-10-18 00:00:00'),
  568: Timestamp('2021-10-19 00:00:00'),
  569: Timestamp('2021-10-20 00:00:00'),
  570: Timestamp('2021-10-21 00:00:00'),
  571: Timestamp('2021-10-22 00:00:00'),
  572: Timestamp('2021-10-23 00:00:00'),
  573: Timestamp('2021-10-24 00:00:00'),
  574: Timestamp('2021-10-25 00:00:00'),
  575: Timestamp('2021-10-26 00:00:00'),
  576: Timestamp('2021-10-27 00:00:00'),
  577: Timestamp('2021-10-28 00:00:00'),
  578: Timestamp('2021-10-29 00:00:00'),
  579: Timestamp('2021-10-30 00:00:00'),
  580: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00')},
 'Nevents': {552: 2.0,
  553: 2.0,
  554: 2.0,
  555: 3.0,
  556: 3.0,
  557: 2.0,
  558: 2.0,
  559: 2.0,
  560: 2.0,
  561: 1.0,
  562: 2.0,
  563: 4.0,
  564: 2.0,
  565: 3.0,
  566: 4.0,
  567: 2.0,
  568: 2.0,
  569: 2.0,
  570: 5.0,
  571: 2.0,
  572: 4.0,
  573: 3.0,
  574: 1.0,
  575: 2.0,
  576: 3.0,
  577: 1.0,
  578: 2.0,
  579: 2.0,
  580: 2.0}})

# raw event line
raw = alt.Chart(dfs).mark_line(color='light grey').encode(
    x=alt.X('Date:T', axis=alt.Axis(format='%Y-%b-%d')),
    y='Nevents:Q'
    ).properties(width = 800, height = 400).interactive(bind_y=False)

# rolling average line, ideally interactive
slider = alt.binding_range(min=1, max=42, step=1, name='av_int:')
op_var = alt.param(value=4, bind=slider)

av_line = alt.Chart(dfs).mark_line(
    color='red',
    size=3
).encode(
    x='Date:T',
    y='rolling_mean:Q',
    tooltip='rolling_mean:Q'
).transform_window(
    rolling_mean='mean(Nevents)',
    frame=[-5,0] # I cannot figure out how to pass a variable to this in altair or vega-lite
    # frame=[{"params": "op_var"},0] # this is effectively what I want to do
).add_params(op_var)

raw + av_line
```

Comment: Please include sample data so that others can easily test your code